# How would you design class structure for a building, floors and space- Object-Oriented

Tags: java, c++, oop, object-oriented-analysis, class-structure

What would be an elegant OOP design for these requirements?

*"Design class structure for a building, floors and space. The space can be an apartment, a store or an office. Include any properties, fields and methods you think would be interesting to have."*

I've tried this but i think it's not a good solution:

```
space {
    floor {
    }
    building {
        floor{
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some pseduo C++ to get you started.  I didn't provide any public members - just structures with relationships to get you started.

As for the issue of "a space can belong in more than one building".  That's an exercise, I'll leave up to you.

```
class Building;
class Space;
class Floor;

class Building
{
   int number_of_floors;
   vector<Floor*> _floors;  // list of floors in the building

   // building specific data
   string name;
   string address;
};

class Floor
{
   Building* pBuilding; // building for which this floor belongs
   int floor_number;    // the floor number (e.g 1-99)
   vector<Space*>; // list of spaces on this floor
}; 


class Space
{
public:
    enum SpaceType
    {
        Apartment,
        Store,
        Office
    };

private:
    SpaceType _spacetype;
    Floor* pFloor;   // floor in which this space exists on
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze the requirements.

You have 3 objects; building, floor, and space.

A building can have one or more floors.

A floor can have one or more spaces.

You should be able to develop objects and their relationships from this.

Comment: however a space can have one of more building too, this will complicate the problem

Comment: Not really.  They are separate spaces, even if they belong to the same owner.